# Powershell Email user

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I have this script that works but I'm looking for a solution that does not use a txt file. You have an idea of ​​how I can do that

Basically I want to inform users that they must reboot to complete the installation of Windows updates.

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administrat ion") | out-null 
if (!$wsus) { 
    $wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::GetUpdateServer(); 
} 

$computerScope = new-object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope; 
$computerScope.IncludedInstallationStates = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateInstallationStates]::InstalledPendingReboot; 

$updateScope = new-object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope; 
$updateScope.IncludedInstallationStates = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateInstallationStates]::InstalledPendingReboot; 

$computers = $wsus.GetComputerTargets($computerScope); 

$Usernames = foreach ($Computer in $computers) {

$Error.Clear()
(get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computer.FullDomainName -  ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).UserName.Split("\")[1]  
} 


$Emailadress = ForEach ($Username in $Usernames) { 

Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -Properties EmailAddress | select EmailAddress } $Emailadress | Out-File C:\Myscript\email.txt

$Emails = Get-Content C:\Myscript\email.txt

 ForEach ($Email in $Emails) {

$WarnMsg = "
<p style='font-family:arial'>Bonjour,</p>
<p style='font-family:arial'>Votre ordinateur dois être redémaré pour finir l'installation de mise à jours,</p>
<p style='font-family:arial'>Merci.</p>"
$Enc  = New-Object System.Text.utf8encoding

send-mailmessage -to $Email -from noreply@noreply.com -Subject "Mise à jours" -body $WarnMsg  -smtpserver x.x.x.x -BodyAsHtml -Encoding $Enc}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration") | Out-Null

if (!$wsus) { 
    $wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::GetUpdateServer()
}

$computerScope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ComputerTargetScope
$computerScope.IncludedInstallationStates = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateInstallationStates]::InstalledPendingReboot

$updateScope = New-Object Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateScope
$updateScope.IncludedInstallationStates = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.UpdateInstallationStates]::InstalledPendingReboot

$computers = $wsus.GetComputerTargets($computerScope)

$Usernames = foreach ($Computer in $computers) {
    $Error.Clear()
    (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computer.FullDomainName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).UserName.Split("\")[1]
}

#this does not change, no need to put it in the foreach loop
$WarnMsg = "<p style='font-family:arial'>Bonjour,</p>
<p style='font-family:arial'>Votre ordinateur doit être redémarré pour finir l'installation de mises à jour,</p>
<p style='font-family:arial'>Merci.</p>"
$Enc = New-Object System.Text.utf8encoding

#for each user
foreach($Username in $Usernames) {
    #get email address
    $emailAddress = Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -Properties EmailAddress | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EmailAddress

    #use it to send a mail
    Send-MailMessage -To $emailAddress -From noreply@noreply.com -Subject "Mises à jour" -Body $WarnMsg  -SmtpServer x.x.x.x -BodyAsHtml -Encoding $Enc
}
```

Also, trailing `;` is not needed in PowerShell. It can be used to put multiple commands on the same line, but it's usually much less readable.

(je me suis permis de corriger les petites fautes de français ^^)